# VirtualBox won't start - NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-10

I have Windows 10 host and VirtualBox 5.0.10. I am trying to launch Ubuntu as guest OS and getting this error:

> 134c.754: supR3HardenedWinReadErrorInfoDevice: 'RTLdrOpenWithReader failed: -626 (Image='\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\S'
>
> 134c.754: Error -626 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=3)
>
> 134c.754: NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: Unknown Status -626 (0xfffffd8e) (rcNt=0xe986fd8e)
>
> VBoxDrvStub error: RTLdrOpenWithReader failed: -626 (Image='\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\S
>
> 2ea4.2960: supR3HardenedWinCheckChild: enmRequest=2 rc=-626 enmWhat=3 supR3HardenedWinReSpawn: NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: Unknown Status -626 (0xfffffd8e) (rcNt=0xe986fd8e)
>
> VBoxDrvStub error: RTLdrOpenWithReader failed: -626 (Image='\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\S
>
> 2ea4.2960: Error -626 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=3)
>
> 2ea4.2960: NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: Unknown Status -626 (0xfffffd8e) (rcNt=0xe986fd8e)
> VBoxDrvStub error: RTLdrOpenWithReader failed: -626 (Image='\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\S

This host used to work on Win7 and not since I have upgraded to Win10

Please help me fix this issue

Error screen shot as under and complete error log [here](http://justpaste.it/pcbx).

[image]

Comment: This is what seems to help for me, but maybe its only similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/58799084/3419535 , error message is similar, though parameter different

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer elsewhere: however, I must note, that I ended up with another error not having multiple virtual screens or graphical options in configuration, reinstalling helped, but this error returned and the solution stopped to work, what effectively helped after was uninstalling and reinstalling VirtualBox - perhaps also due to error message

> C: Program Files\ Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers is unavailable. If the location is on this PC, make sure the device or drive is connected or the disc is inserted, and then try again

while the folder existed; I checked manually

From https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=66442#p314829:

> ###### RE: NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: 0xc000000034:
>
> Postby [kpenrose](https://forums.virtualbox.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=81444&sid=f82feeb3e0845199465580760fe82558) » 6. Mar 2015, 19:15
>
> Okay - got it working. Here's what I did.
>
> Went to the C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv
> directory, right clicked on VBoxDrv.inf and selected Install. I then
> went back to my console and typed 'sc start vboxdrv' and got this:
>
> ```
> SERVICE_NAME: vboxdrv
>         TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
>         STATE              : 4  RUNNING
>                                 (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
>         WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
>         SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
>         CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
>         WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
>         PID                : 0
>         FLAGS              :
> ```
>
> Went back to VirtualBox and was able to start the Ubuntu virtual
> machine.

My similar error:

[image]

> VirtualBox - Error In supR3Hardened WinkeSpawn
>
> **NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: Unknown Status -5633
> (0xffffe9ff) (rcNt=0xe986e9ff) VBoxDrvStub error: Unknown image file
> \Device \HarddiskVolume4\Program
> Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe at 00007ff7f1b90000.
> (rc83Exp--91) (rc=-5633)**
>
> Make sure the kernel module has been loaded successfully.
>
> where: supR3HardenedWinReSpawn what: 3
> VERR_SUP_VP_NOT_KNOWN_DLL_OR_EXE (-5633) - Process Verification
> Failure: An unknown and unwanted DLL was found loaded into the
> process.

other accompanying errors
[image]

[image]

> VirtualBox - Error In supR3HardenedWinReSpawn
>
> **NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: 0xc000000e
> STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE (160 retries) (rc=-101)**
>
> Make sure the kernel
> module has been loaded successfully.
>
> where: supR3HardenedWinReSpawn
> what: 3 VERR_OPEN_FAILED (-101) - File/ Device open failed. Driver is
> probably stuck stopping/starting. Try 'sc. exe query vboxdrv' to get
> more information about its state. Rebooting may actually help.

Comment: I hit the "-5633" error code, and for me the solution was simply to restart my host computer. (for a second time, after installing VirtualBox)

Answer (score 0):

It worked with test build, VirtualBox 5.0.11 fixes the problem

Comment: I don't think it's a version-specific, same problem 4 years later, version 6.0.14, I think it is just a coincidence that a reinstall of any version helps to fix it, but not a particular version

Comment: @FantomX1 Yes, I think that's often the case, that reinstalling VirtualBox -- or even just restarting the host PC a second time -- fixes the issue. For example, I hit the "-5633" error code, and for me the solution was simply to restart my host computer. (for a second time, after installing VirtualBox)